# ArchLinux mounts filesystem with no entries in /etc/fstab

Tags: arch-linux, mount

I have successfully installed ArchLinux.

While I check `/etc/fstab` entries I do not see any mounts, even the root partition is omitted. However when I execute `mount`, it shows the mount-points of each on my system.

My question is how my file-system gets mounted. Would it have something to do with `systemd`?

Here is the output of `mount`

```
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)            
sys on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)   
dev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=924480k,nr_inodes=231120,mode=755)
run on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,mode=755)  
/dev/mapper/vg_archlinux-lv_root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)   
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```

Comment: Did you check [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab)? Could you add the output of `/etc/fstab` and `mount` as well? Could you explain the assumption that it has something to do with `systemd`?

Comment: I assume that `udev` got something to do with it.

Comment: @utrecht: for your reference i added the output of `mount`. However, as i said my /etc/fstab is an empty file.

Comment: @krs4keshara Could you indicate which version of ArchLinux you are using? According to [this documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab) the `/etc/fstab` should contain content. Did you run `lsblk -f`?

Comment: @utrecht: yeah, i checked that doc. It gives an output of what it supposed to when i execute `lsblk -f` according to the mentioned document. But what i am still trying to understand how on earth my file-system gets mounted with empty /etc/fstab.

Comment: @krs4keshara Have you read [this Q&A](http://superuser.com/questions/522794/how-can-mount-work-with-an-empty-fstab) as well?

Comment: @utrecht: Thanks for the link. As it said, system can mount its filesystem without ever accessing /etc/fstab. But knowing that, i still want to know how that thing happens? Do you have any info about that.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved! - many thanks to utrecht.

what i learn during this is that any system do mounts /root partition using the bootloader in the first place. After that they are remounted by systemd if only they exist in /etc/fstab.

Due to some reason, my `/etc/fstab` did not generate as it should withing the installation. But the reason it worked was that bootloader mount required mount-points when the system boots.

Comment: `/boot/` is not remounted (as your `mount` output shows), nor does it need to be...